# Any other ways to update Google Search Result for my website?? (meta tag doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The Google search result of the website doesn't display the text I want it to display. I've put meta tag: nosnippet and put meta tag description, but the Google Search result still remains the same old text.

Could someone kindly point out the resources/ tools I could use to troubleshoot this issue??

ps: I'm using React to build my website

Thank you! I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can server-side render your react app. There are many universal rendering boilerplates available, try one of them or try using airbnb-hypernova if you can manage.

Another approach is prerendering, try this.
https://www.prerender.cloud/

There is no other way to do this except prerendering or server side rendering your app.